# DataContext changes depending on Authorization claims

Tags: c#, wcf

I have implemented Service class, let's say "DataSourceService". Now i want to expose it through WCF and make it REST. There are no problems, this can be easily done in WCF.

But here comes, I would say, architecture question.

So let's say that I have a Method:

```
 IEnumerable<string> ReadAllInventoryItems()
```

The Problem that I have to return `IEnumerable<string>` depending on User Authorization claims(Roles or Permissions etc.).
I could do that by validating these Claims in each method of DataSourceService.
Something like that:

```
IEnumerable<string> ReadAllInventoryItems()
{
     var companyName = ReadCompanyNameFromAuthorisationContext();
     var items = ReadAll().Where( i => i.CompanyName == companyName).ToList();
     return Items;
}
```

I would say that there is one big problem with the approach.
Namely: DataSourceService becomes unusable without this "Claims" context.
I have to prepare the Claims or UserIdentity context for every call when I would use it without WCF.

So next step for me was "thinking about WCF IDispatchMessageInspector" but then I realized that I have to implement one IDispatchMessageInspector and one OperationInvoker and then I could decorate Web Service Methods with some kind of Attribute with Permissions(this attributes would be used later in OperationInvoker).

Finally I would get:

```
    [AuthorizationFiltering]
    IEnumerable<string> ReadAllInventoryItems()
    {         
         var items = ReadAll().Where( i => i.CompanyName == companyName).ToList();
         return Items;
    }
```

What do you think about that?

Should I stick with "validating these Claims in each method of DataSourceService"
or WCF IDispatchMessageInspector, MethodInvoker story is not so bad...

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it all depends on how you want to design your API, I think obscuring a "filter" within your authorization context (like in your claims) is not a good idea if you want your API to be public and intuitive for the caller, if I would have to call your service I would have to know precisely what kind of claim are you expecting from your caller.

However, and if all your callers know that you are using Claims-based authorization, you can design your methods to "require" certain claims, then you're approach is just fine. And you can use for example something similar to:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = ManagersWithInventory)]
```

Remember though, that if the caller does not possess this specific claims, he won't be able to call the method. So that could be the behavior desired or not.

In a very simple case, I would just design a service call with an explicit "filter" like

```
MyService.GetInventoryByReferenceId(string Id)
```

That contract makes the call very intuitive, and is the responsibility of the caller to decide how the filter is populated.

***EDIT***

ok, I'm not saying that your implementing IDispatchMessageInspector  is wrong, but probably somewhat overkill because you are "sniffing" for data unnecesarily and yet you have to make another external roundtrips to get identity of the caller.

I think a much better approach is to use the "real" claims identity : Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll in both sides and work with claims transparently letting WCF transport the credentials with it.

One thing to notice, your old desktop applications calling your service will still e able to work because WIF wraps the previous IIdentity in IClaimsIdentity so you can even work with your "User" with or without claims (on your service side)

hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. What I am really would like to achieve. I have an Assembly with Services these Services have no idea about Authorization etc. and I would like to keep it so. For Instance, I am using it in internal Desktop Tool that just call it and recieves all information. From other side, I would like to apply Authorisation context to the data but only for WCF endpoint. This is why I have had the IDispatchMessageInspector idea. What do you think?

Comment: @VladDE there is one thing I don't get, maybe you can clear that for me, when you call your service from your Desktop application, are you already sending claims? or is it just an anonymous call? What I mean is, where are you planning to use claims, in your client or your service?

Comment: Yes it just anonymous call. It's just a class... I instantiate it and call ReadAllInventoryItems.

Comment: Thank you for the post update. Finnaly I've done it a bit different. Please see my updated post.

Comment: @VladDE is good to know you fixed it, but perhaps as reference for others you might want to separate your question from your own answer and let everyone to vote for separate issues. cheers,

Answer (score 0):

**Update/ Solution?:**

After some thoughts and Jorge Alvarado comments. I had decided to implement following thing.

So...
The Service class doesn't know about the security context.
What it does know althrough that there is a Property(enumeration) "CompanyName".
For Instance:

```
public ClientEnumerationType? CurrentClient { get; set; }
```

and when I service wants to return a result from ReadInventory function I have following code:

```
IEnumerable<string> ReadAllInventoryItems()
{
     var items = ReadAll();

     return CurrentClient.HasValue ? FilterByClient(items, urrentClient.Value).ToList() : items;
}
```

So, that implementation allows me to use that class outside the WCF without any problems.

What about WCF?
I was thinking what exactly I need from WCF and actually I need only one thing. Authorize client, instantiate service class and set value CurrentClient property.

To make that possible, I have implemented several things.

**1) IEndpointBehavior**

I need it to install Message Inspector and InstanceProvider and ParameterInspectors for each of Contract Methods.

**2) IDispatchMessageInspector**

Takes the WCF message, extracts token from the request, validates the token and sets Thread.CurrentPrincipal to ClaimsPrincipal with all claims values from the request.

**3)IParameterInspector**

I need it to validate Claim = Action for each method in the contract.
For Instance I have:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [ClaimActionRequred(Action = "read")]        
    IEnumerable<string> ReadAllInventoryItems()
```

That means that I Identity Provider should provide Action claim for client token.
And that claim value is being analysed in IParameterInspector, before the actual call being made.

**4) Last piece - IInstanceProvider**

All i need is, instantiate ServiceClass and pass CurrentClient property value depending on a Claim Value.

Done.

I am not sure that I've done it right. But this is solustion that I've had been made.